# Is there a way to specify image permissions when creating an image using virt-install?

Tags: permissions, virtualization, kvm-virtualization

I'm using a virt-install command to create a .qcow2 image which is supposed to be used as a template. This template should be cloned (using qemu-img create) when certain functions in the framework I'm working on are called. So far, our only way of making this work is by either manually changing the template's owner, giving everyone read and write permissions (the default is root/root with permissions 600) or running our  scripts as root.

Is there a way to make virt-install create images with the currently logged in user as a owner?

Edit: The currently used desktop Ubuntu version is the 19.10, although we also use a server with Ubuntu 18.04 - our main concern as of right is the desktop version. I should add that the created pool used in the virt-install command is not located in the default directory.

Comment: To start with, which version of Linux have you installed  (Ubuntu server, Ubuntu desktop, Kubuntu, Lubuntu, Xubuntu, Ubuntu MATE, et al.) , and which release number?  Different releases have different tools for us to recommend. Please click [edit] and add that vital information to your question so all the facts we need are in the question. Please don't use Add Comment, since that's our channel to you. All facts about your system should go in the Question with [edit]